# Add Article Select Dropdown for About Us page Joomla

Tags: drop-down-menu, joomla

In my Joomla website I need to include select dropdown on my About Us page to select Another article i have prepared.

I have prepared a article called "In Sinhala" to display same "About Us" article in sinhala language. when user select In sinhala from drop down, user will be able to see the about us article in sinhala language that i have prepared in sinhala language.. I have used language translators but was not help full for my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create multi language site and prepend language A menu item to language B menu item, so if user switch language he will stay in same menu.

or

you can create a simple module, where you will be fetching article based on dropdown change.

regards